Grub is not picking up Windows-10 drive but EFI is
/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi    not found
I ran the sudo grub-update and rechecked my etc/grub.d/40_custom file settings.  Now it is executing the 40_custom file but apparently I have a error in how it boots into Windows 10 Pro.  The 40_custom is executable ls -la etc/grub.d/40_custom
-rwxr-xrwx 1 root root 360
But the /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi  is not found.
grub comes up with the following menu
*Ubuntu
Advanced options for Ubuntu
UEFI Firmware Settings
Windows X Homer Simpson

selecting Windows X Homer Simpson results in the following:
 error: unknown filesystem
    Press any key to continue...

so I hit 'Esc', it goes to the grub menu, e.g.
grub>
I type 'exit'
it goes to fwupd-EFI version 1.4 and then after 10 seconds or so boots Windows 10 Pro 64 bit which is what I want.
So I'm making progress I just need to figure out the correct Windows bootloader yes it is /dev/nvme0n1p1   Also identified as hd0,gpt1    from the Grub menu.
Device             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    1968127   1966080   960M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2   1968128  212905983 210937856 100.6G Linux 
filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 212905984  466812927 253906944 121.1G Linux swap
/dev/nvme0n1p4 466812928 1000214527 533401600 254.3G Linux 
filesystem

Background
Have an Ubuntu 22.04 system which runs on a modern HP Z4 G4 Server (64 GB).  I have a very old (20 yrs?) Desktop computer running Windows-10, booting from a new SSD (1TB) and with a 2 TB data HDD.
Moved my 2 Windows drives to my HP Server to have it duel boot Windows & Linux.
I've followed the instructions on this link:
How can I add Windows 11 to grub menu?
I scanned my drives and added the UUID of the Windows boot drive (SSD,1.0 TB WDC) to the file etc/grub.d/40_custom
grub
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
# GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=20
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="Ubi 22.04"

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
# GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
# GRUB_INIT_TUNE="640 440 1 330 1 277 1 880 1"
GRUB_INIT_TUNE="950 392 3 0 6 392 3 0 6 466 3 0 3 523 3 0 3 392 3 0 6"

40_custom
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry 'Windows X Homer Simpson' {

insmod part_gpt
insmod fat
set root='hd0:gpt1'
# if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
# search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0:gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0:gpt1 
# else 
# search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root XXXX-XXXX
# fi
chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}


Grub only boots working Windows. And is your Windows in UEFI mode, an old system could be the old BIOS/MBR, not newer UEFI/gpt. And since Windows 8,  Windows Product key is in UEFI. So not sure you can even move Windows from one system to another as product key will not match.

/etc/grub.d/40_custom must be executable, perhaps you need to run sudo chmod +x /etc/grub.d/40_custom. If the file is not executable, the file will not be executed during update-grub.

I have a rig with 24.04 alongside WIN10. If memory serves I just modified the config file /etc/default/grub and set: -
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true

To
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

I also added the same line as the last uncommented thing in the file. I am not sure why now.
You then have to update grub.
sudo update-grub

If you have secure boot enabled I believe grub will check this and will not add anything that it cannot verify as such.

It worked for me.

Extra1
Just to check the file you modified as described above is: -
/etc/default/grub

Can you try to boot with Secure boot switched off? (I assume it is enabled?) Clearly there is a risk involved which you will have to assess and take precautions. It will not add WIN10 if it cannot verify the target with its security keys. (At least it doesn't on mine.)
To check if your modified 40_custom is being picked up you could add something that you know already works. You could try adding another copy of the Ubuntu you already have. (I have never tried this so I am not sure if grub will duplicate but it is worth a try.)
You can obtain a menu entry from the /boot/grub/grub.cfg but be very careful not to modify this file although I would think a 'update-grub' would regenerate it.
You might like to check that your 40_custom file is still executable. you can do this with: -
 ls -la /etc/grub.d/40_custom

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 214 Apr  4 11:12 /etc/grub.d/40_custom

Detail on using custom grub: -
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus
I hope this is of some help.
Extra2
My grub compared...
Note: This is copied 1 char at a time from a second machine.
insmod part_gpt
insmod fat
set root='hd0:gpt4'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0:gpt4 --hint-efi=hd0:gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0:gpt4 XXXX-XXXX
else 
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root XXXX-XXXX
fi
chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi

I note, in particular that there is no '(${root})' in the chainloader line.
I thought this also might help.
Extra3:
In your Custom_40 you don't seem to have set root anywhere, (see the copy of my grub Win10 boot script above).
set root='hd0:gpt4'

That is grub for my UEFI partition. Try and add that to your 40_custom pointing at your UEFI and see if that makes it work.
You will probably need the insmod commands (see above) to make this bit work too.
To find out what grub calls each disk/partition see: -
https://superuser.com/questions/1258525/how-do-i-list-my-devices-in-grub
Get to grub menu and then type 'c' to get to grub prompt. Then type ls -l then ls (hd0,1)/ (Substituting your selected disk at start) should list UEFI directory tree. Might need the insmod stuff again here.)
Hope this is of some help.

I added "GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false" to the end of my grub but it made no difference.  Is there any way I can verify that 40_custom is even being read?

Added Extra1 to answer

Added Extra2 to answer

@NicholasBourbaki You need to run sudo update-grub everytime after you make changes to /etc/default/grub or any file in /etc/grub.d to write the changes to /boot/grub/grub.cfg. I write this comment sInce you never mentioned runnig this command.

Hi David & thanks. I upvoted your ansr restoring it to 0 since any attempt at an answer should not be downvotd.   With sudo update-grub, I didn't think I needed to since I did a reboot.  But perhaps I may need to?    By sheer luck I managed to drop out of the grub menu, which causes the computer to do a : "fwupd-EFI version 1.4". From there it will automatically boot into my old Windows installation and sees all my Windows apps.  Still I think I need to fix things so as to get a cleaner boot procedure & menu.

@NicholasBourbaki As I stated in my comment above, you need to run sudo update-grub to make your changes work. See also my comment under your question about execute permission.

I also set    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi   no (${root})   but it didn't work.

Added Extra3 to answer

I need to fix the set root='hd0:gpt4' part of my 40_custom file. Of course I need to figure out the appropriate name for my 1 TB WDC boot drive for Windows first. Will work on that part & update when I have it fixed.  It definitely now reads the 40_custom as it offers to boot "Windows home" (which I typed by accident) in the menu. I have Windows 10 Pro.

Hi @david   Tried some varients but all I could get was "unrecognized filesystem" rather than error: file '/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi' not found    The Ubuntu app Disk identified hd0,1 as ntfs so I tried that instead of FAT which I think the ls -l returned.  My 40_custom is executable & I am doing sudo update-grub all the time.  At least it does work when I exit the grub menu and somehow runs the correct efi but I don't know how it does it.

I looked at mine. My UEFI is on the fourth partition of a GPT disk. So ls -1 (hd0,gpt4)/ gives efi/ & System Volume Information/  So I would bet if you start with the 'insmod part_gpt' and 'insmod fat' then being that your EFI is on the first partition I would put  set root='hd0:gpt1'  (Which you list as one of its identities (from grub menu) in your original question details.) I do believe those insmod drivers? are crucial to this. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259069/how-to-start-a-windows-partition-from-the-grub-command-line for a template.
