UUID=xxx does not exist. Dropping to a shell on standard (no dual boot) on Lenovo Idea Pad 3
I know there are duplicates of this, and I have gone thru many of them. Most promising I thought were UUID=xxx does not exist. Dropping to a shell
and ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxxx does not exist. Dropping to a shell ... no dual boot ... I sense my /boot/efi may be somehow corrupt.
I have done all that to no avail. the primary error that I see is:
ALERT: UUID=6fce33c4-a9bb-444c-bb8a-c1ed59b986a3 does not exist.  Dropping to a shell.
My problem started after I applied some software while on Ubuntu 22.04.  I can start up in recovery mode. I have run fsck on /boot/efi.
Details:
blkid (note, nothing shows up for /dev/nvme0n1p1)
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="6fce33c4-a9bb-444c-bb8a-c1ed59b986a3" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="0cd0904e-a12f-4a8d-ab3f-ad85c45a7082"

blkid --uuid 6fce33c4-a9bb-444c-bb8a-c1ed59b986a3mm :
/dev/nvme0n1p2 (this is mounted at /)
blkid --uuid 6307-B41C
/dev/nvme0n1p1  (this is /boot/efi)

df :
 Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs            1179464     2280   1177184   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p2 244506940 57914480 174099404  25% /
tmpfs            5897316   117260   5780056   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        8      5112   1% /run/lock
efivarfs             184       95        85  53% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
/dev/nvme0n1p1    523248     6288    516960   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs            1179460      136   1179324   1% /run/user/1000

fstab :
UUID=6fce33c4-a9bb-444c-bb8a-c1ed59b986a3 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
 /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
**UUID=6307-B41C**  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

fdisk -l  (ignoring all loop entries)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors  
Disk model: KBG40ZNT256G TOSHIBA MEMORY  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
Disklabel type: gpt  
Disk identifier: F9060F62-5530-4003-B7BA-BBA3CF4F5F54  

Device           Start       End   Sectors  Size Type  
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048   1050623   1048576  512M EFI System  
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624 500117503 499066880  238G Linux filesystem  

cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS"  
NAME="Ubuntu"  
VERSION_ID="24.04"  
VERSION="24.04.1 LTS (Noble Numbat)"  
VERSION_CODENAME=noble  
ID=ubuntu  
ID_LIKE=debian  
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"  
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"  
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"  
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"  
UBUNTU_CODENAME=noble  
LOGO=ubuntu-logo  

lsb_release -a :
No LSB modules are available.  
Distributor ID: Ubuntu  
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS  
Release:    24.04  
Codename:   noble  

hostnamectl :
 Static hostname: mjcasile-IdeaPad-3-15IIL05  
       Icon name: computer-laptop  
         Chassis: laptop   
      Machine ID: 32767bc4a6ea4c75b2eb24c855255e99  
         Boot ID: a58c217abae64b8fb394aacd5fa86919  
Operating System: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS              
          Kernel: Linux 6.8.0-41-generic  
    Architecture: x86-64  
 Hardware Vendor: Lenovo  
  Hardware Model: IdeaPad 3 15IIL05  
Firmware Version: EMCN40WW  
   Firmware Date: Mon 2020-08-10  
    Firmware Age: 4y 3w 6d           

When I power down after initramfs prompt ... I come to screen with the following options:
*Ubuntu
Advanced options for Ubuntu
Memory test (memtest 86+x87.efi)
Memory test (memtest 86+x87.efi, serial console)
UEFI Firmware Settings
When I do UEFI Firmware Settings, I verify that boot from USB is enabled
I have tried all of the options, but generally do Advanced options for Ubuntu and select one of the recovery options (6.8.0.41 or 6.8.0.40)
I have tried going back to legacy boot (instead of UEFI) to no avail.
I attempted this once and have been on UEFI before and since. I updated my USB boot drive and came up with that (to do the mount work from one of the prior answers).  I had to use the F12 trick, but that is done and it did not solve the problem.  <Escape> on boot does get me to a grub prompt.  Not in my comfort zone/happy place. I hope someone can see something I don't.
I have run fsck on /dev/nvme0n1p2 and /dev/nvme0n1p1 .  On nvme0n1p2 it said it was clean and gave me block counts.  Not much info nvme0n1p1.
From problem ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxxx does not exist. Dropping to a shell  ... I have come up on my USB drive and gone thru the instructions to replace /proc /dev and /sys with those directories from the USB drive install.
Was not quite clear where to replace the UUID=... with root=/dev/nvme0n1p2 ... so I did it in /etc/fstab ... and it did not change anything.
Currently, the way I get to advanced options (from which I run in recovery mode) is that when I fail and go to initramfs prompt, I power down  and power back up ... then the advanced options menu appears.
In getting to ubuntu menu, I selected advanced options, then when I selected 6.8.0.41 recovery, I hit 'e' instead of enter and got this:
getparams 'Ubuntu, with Linux 6.8.0.41 generic (recovery mode)'
recordfail
load-video
insmod gzio
if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod zxio; insmod lzopio; fi
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6fce33c4-a9bb-444c-bb8a-c1ed59b986a3
echo  'Loading Linux 6.8.0.41-generic ...'
linux /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.041-generic root=UUID=6fce33c4-a9bb-444c-bb8a-c1ed59b986a3 ro recovery nomodeset dis-ucode_ ...
echo  'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
initrd   /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0.41-generic
Note the above was taken with a cell phone camera and transcribed .. but it should be relatively accurate.
I did the grub commandline modification, switch root=UID=... to
root=/dev/nvme0n1p2 ... when I ran it against the 6.8.0.41 (not recovery) ... I still dropped into initramfs prompt, but the instead:
ALERT! /dev/nvme0n1p2 does not exist.  Dropping to a shell!

If you press escape key just after UEFI/BIOS screen, do you get grub menu? And then boot recovery mode? Do not turn on legacy/BIOS/CSM mode if booting in UEFI as that will just confuse things. Then have you run the repair options? First thing to try is fsck of ext4 partition. It has to be unmounted so recovery mode before mounting or use a live installer. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1474846/fixing-bad-superblock-on-ssd-drive-is-e2fsck-safe-to-run

You can't flip between legacy boot and efi boot without reinstalling grub.  Change it to what it was when you installed grub, interrupt the grub menu, edit the command line to remove the UUID= and replace it with root=/dev/nvme0n1p2 and see if it boots normally.  Then run update-grub

Escape on restart DID indeed get me to a grub prompt (from which I knew not what to do).  I booted from my USB drive and ran fsck on /dev/nvme01p2 which said that the drive was clean and gave me a count (I saved the output to a file in the /tmp/ directory ... not realizing that gets wiped on restarts ... can run again if it helps).  I tried the legacy boot one time ... saw it did not help and have been UEFI all other times.  Not sure of the other repair options other than fsck and the ones I did tied to one of the similar entries out here which replace /dev /proc and /sys from usb

Was not quite clear where to replace the UUID=... with root=/dev/nvme0n1p2 ... so I did it in /etc/fstab ... and it did not change anything.  Went to initramfs and still got Alert based on UUID.  Looked in grub.cfg but it was a script w/many refs to UUID.  And on getting to advanced menu, when I fail and get to initramfs prompt I power down and power back up and get advanced menu.  I can get to grub menu, but am not sure what to do there.  Also not sure where the UUID=xxx to root=/dev/nvme0n1p2 happens.

comments should be reserved for others to ask you for clarifications which you should then include in your question. Please [edit] accordingly

When you get to grub menu, select the menu to want to boot (top?) and type 'e' instead of 'return'. From there you can modify the grub boot script and then Ctl-X or F10 to continue to boot. This change is only temporary for experimentation.

My understanding is the recovery mode works - which you have appended to your question the boot script for. I think we want to see the boot script for the boot that fails. The failing boot script is also the one you should attempt to modify (changing UUID to PATH) as described above. (For testing you can probably delete the whole IF...FI loop (but don't quite me on it.)

You need to format your boot program script. Select & use {} button. I did notice you have missed out (or is missing) the setting of root. Somewhere you need set--  root='hd0,gpt6'  -- It might not be '6'.It should point to your UEFI partition. I suspect you just missed the line when copying it. Also see link https://askubuntu.com/questions/1521251/grub-is-not-picking-up-windows-10-drive-but-efi-is/1521253#1521253 the answer, which is an example of how it worked (my boot script then) a few weeks ago. The 'root' bit is still in the latest though. Try just adding the 'root' bit.

Did you try to rebuild the initramfs? (See details at the end of the answer below).

Booting from a drop down grub command line.
Assuming that you are able to boot grub to a grub prompt (not at grub rescue prompt). Doing this starts the secure boot sequence but you might like to attempt the same thing with secure boot switched off, (I have secure boot on).
grub menu -> e to edit the current boot and Ctl-C or F2 to get to grub prompt. (TAB list all possible commands) There is a history and you can TAB to complete a path.
grub> set pager=1

grub> ls
(hd0) (hd0,gpt8) (hd0,gpt7) (hd0,gpt6) (hd0,gpt5) (hd0,gpt4) (hd0,gpt3) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1) hd1...

You need to look through all the above until you find the Ubuntu source directory.
grub> ls (hd0,gpt6)/
lost+found/  boot/ home/ bin/ lib lib64 sbin bin.usr-is-merged/ cdrom/ dev/ etc/ lib.usr-is-merged/ media/ mnt/ opt/ proc/ root/ run/ sbin.usr-is-merged/  snap/ srv sys/ tmp/ usr/ var/ swap.img

Look in the /boot directory for both the vmlinux... file and the initrd... file.
grub> ls (hd0,gpt6)/boot
vmlinuz-6.8.0-44-generic initrd.img-6.8.0-44-generic ...

And now do the following (substitute gpt6 with your discovered partition): -
grub> recordfail

grub> load_video

grub> gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode

grub> insmod gzio

grub> insmod part_gpt

grub> insmod ext2

grub> set root='hd0,gpt6'

grub> linux /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-44-generic root=UUID=6fce33c4-a9bb-444c-bb8a-c1ed59b986a3 ro quiet splash $vt_handoff

grub> initrd /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-44-generic

grub> boot

It will appear to freeze so give it some time. The first sign of success is the spash screen.
I have just done this on my PC and it worked on the third go. You have to type it all by hand so it is very easy to make a mistake.
If you do manage to successfully boot it then the first thing you should do is reinstall grub.
{Your booting disk = /dev/nvme0n1}
sudo grub-install --target=i386-efi /dev/nvme0n1 

sudo update-grub


So you can boot to your previous kernel but not the current one.
As you have now successfully booted to the previous kernel (using this method) it suggests that your current initramfs has been corrupted. Boot to the previous kernel and try to rebuild the initramfs for the broken one: -
Again high risk so make sure everything is backed up.
sudo update-initramfs -c -k 6.8.0-44-generic

Hopefully that will fix things.

I have done all of the above and tab completion helped verify that I got it right.  On first pass, I went back to the initramfs prompt and typing Exit brings up the old error:
ALERT!  UUID=6fce33c4-a9bb-444c-bb8a-c1ed59b986a3 does not exist.  Dropping to a shell!
Planning to try it 2 more times just in case.  I get a splash screen every time, but then it pops back to the initramfs prompt.

OK, I ran it again using 6.8.0.41 instead of 6.8.0.44 and I came up!!!  Looking to reinstall grub.  Hopefully afterwards I will be able to boot regular?

Did all of this ... had to do grub-install to x86_64-efi as i386-efi did not exist.  When I restart, I go back to initramfs and I wonder if that is the 6.8.0.41 instead of 6.8.0.44.  Or maybe I somehow need to persist these grub settings.  I went back thru the grub commands and once again it came up clean

I have added details to my answer. How to rebuild the initramfs for the broken kernel boot. (i386-efi --> x86_64-efi flag sounds fine.)

Thanks.  I hope to try that tonight.  When your grub procedure got me out of trouble, I backed everything up, but with a real estate closing today ... I dePrioritized this a bit (band-aid stopped the bleeding).  It scares me a little to possibly wack th emachine but ... since my data is backed up, it's just maybe a day or so to reInstall everything from scratch.

Don't forget to to sort out your /etc/fstab file before you do this. I would recommend you change {errors=remount-ro) to {defaults} and remove those {**} in the efi label field. (At least try this if it doesn't work as it currently is.

I have had trouble getting linux-image-6.8.0-44  or 6.8.0-45 to work through the Linux software updater.  I suspect something in the upgrade is not right. I have a Lenovo laptop of a similar age based on the output of hostnamectl, but I doubt it's a Lenovo issue.  I can't install any new sofware when booted to the newer kernels, so I'm using the Advanced options to make sure I boot into  6.8.0.41 until the issue is resolved.

I am finally getting back to this (using your script to boot each time wasn't that bad).  I got the grub updated, and the latest linux and initrd images are working fine.  the grub updates worked great but when I did
==> sudo update-initramfs -c -k 6.8.0-48-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-48-generic
W: Couldn't identify type of root file system for fsck hook

Rebuilding the ramfs is something you might do when it doesn't boot so you didn't really need to do this. The report is only a harmless warning and probably something you don't need to worry about. See the answer at https://github.com/Qengineering/Jetson-Nano-Ubuntu-20-image/issues/100
