OS won't start after a kernel update
After a kernel update (6.8.0-45 ), the OS won't start correctly, I'm getting the following error:
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?) )
Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev
ALERT! UUID=ebf5d216-7139-4e03-8be1-1a62b83268de does not exist. Dropping to a sh
BusyBox v1.36.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.36.1-6ubuntu3.1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs)

If I restart on an older kernel, the OS start correctly.
I don't understand why the new kernel can't find the uuid (while the older one do) and how to resolve this problem.

This question is similar to: How can I boot with an older kernel version?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It's different because I'm not asking how to boot to another kernel.

I'm aware that the top upvoted answer does not have the information that you're looking for. Please read the rest of this answer and you'll find the relevant information there.

I don't think it does. I don't want to change the kernel at boot. I have an issue with the new kernel that I don't have with the older one.

That's what I wanted you to read. If you have determined that you can successfully boot Ubuntu by using an older kernel version, the next thing to do is to prevent Ubuntu from automatically uninstalling that kernel version by following the instructions in this answer. Short of quoting the entire answer verbatim I don't know what else I can do. I think you might want me to feed you the entire answer one sentence at a time explaining it in detail as I go. You can ask ChatGPT to do that. I ask ChatGPT to do that sometimes.

I'm afraid I have to disagree with you, the next thing is not to prevent Ubuntu from uninstalling that kernel. I expect someone help me to find out why the new kernel can't find my device while the old one does and how to solve that problem. If you're unable to help, it's not a big deal, you're not obliged to find the solution or answer, you can let someone else help me as you're not alone on this server, I guess. My issue was not directed at you specifically.

I have seen something like this before, (Initramfs fails to id the UUID it has) - see answer @ https://askubuntu.com/questions/1525955/uuid-xxx-does-not-exist-dropping-to-a-shell-on-standard-no-dual-boot-on-lenov/1526586#1526586 I am not sure the contributer ever tried the last bit about re-building the initramfs. Alternatively you could try things from the initramfs prompt as detailed at the following link   https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox. Good luck.

Thank you @david for your help. Unfortunately, it didn't work. I've reinstalled Ubuntu.
