Can't boot into Windows 10
I have a Dell Inspiron 5437 laptop which is running on Windows 10. My system is a Legacy based BIOS system. I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows. But, G-RUB dual boot isn't working properly in my device. After installing Ubuntu, I can't boot into Windows again. Actually when I turn on my device, the G-RUB boot menu doesn't show up, it directly boots into Ubuntu. How can I solve the problem?

This question is similar to: Repaired GRUB, now how can I boot into other OSs?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is similar to: Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Welcome to ASK. To get grub legacy menu to appear on boot, repeatadly assert 'shift' during boot ('esc' for UEFI). To make this more perminent see the answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1526795/grub-menu-doesnt-show-any-longer/1526812#1526812 To enable the 'os-prober' if it isn't enabled see  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1521251/grub-is-not-picking-up-windows-10-drive-but-efi-is/1521253#1521253

If it is a Core i7 4500 system, then it is UEFI. with old BIOS boot as an option. My newer Dell says "BIOS" but once in UEFI/BIOS it says it is only UEFI boot. Many systems since about 2020 are UEFI only. How you boot install media, UEFI or BIOS/CSM/Legacy is then how it installs. Then system boot setting UEFI or BIOS controls default boot. Windows should have been UEFI as Microsoft required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode with gpt partitioning since 2012. With that system, you may want to plan conversion to UEFI. But Windows requires BIOS/MBR or  UEFI/gpt and conversion erases drive.
